Как в одном боте использовать джаву и пайтон?
У меня есть тикет бот. После закрытия он генерирует транскрипт тикета. Главная проблема в том, что я использовал библиотеку chat-exporter, он создает ссылку на транскрипт, но через пару дней все скрины из истории удаляются и пишутся, что более не активны. Как я могу написать транскрипт систему на джаве в одном файле и сделать так, чтобы активировался этот код при закрытии тикета, если бот написан на nextcord?
Или может кто знает, как сделать так, чтобы скрины хранились всегда?
